# Android unittests how to create a ContentResolver stub?

Tags: java, android, junit, stub

I've got a following class in my project:

```
public class SmsManager {
  static final Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
  ContentResolver resolver;

  public SmsManager(ContentResolver resolver) {
    this.resolver = resolver;
  }

  ...

}
```

Class will be responsible for operations on sms messages (as Uri message suggested). How can I write unittests for it? How can I easily stub ContentResolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MockContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContentResolver.html) which probably does what you want